# Community user is not getting redirected to Start URL configured in Connected App for SAML

Tags: community, single-sign-on, saml

We are trying to implement SSO using the Salesforce Community to an external PHP site. So, the Salesforce community should be able to login to that external site using community credentials. So far we are able to login with the community user. We have configured these things.

- Created connected app with SAML settings.
- Downloaded metadata of SAML Login Information for Community, used the same in the external website

So when the user logs in using the page from an external site, the user is taken to the community home page. But it should go to the Start URL mentioned in the connected app's SAML settings.

Any Help will be appreciated.